# "Indebted to" or "indebted for"?

Tags: prepositions

I have couple of questions.

First, I'm wondering which one of these is correct:

- I'll **forever** be indebted to you.
- I'll indebted to you **forever**.

And second, I'm not really sure how to use "indebted" in a sentence. What's the difference between "indebted for" and "indebted to"?

Answer (score 2):

In order:

- English adverbs often may move fairly freely in sentences. The only place that *forever* wouldn't be idiomatic is between *to* and *you*. In some cases a different placement may alter the meaning, but not in your example. No matter where the *forever* appears, the sentence means that you will be an eternal debtor.
- The object of the preposition *for* gives the reason for the debt; the object of the preposition *to* names the creditor. For [example](https://books.google.com/books?id=JWhaJ1vWWp0C&pg=PA11&dq=%22indebted%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5q7u96b7SAhUM7IMKHVPbCpwQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22indebted%20for%22&f=false):

  > **To** my editor...I am indebted **for** a good deal more than her meticulous and painstaking editing.

  The author has an obligation **to** his editor; the reason **for** the obligation is the editor's careful copyediting plus, as it turns out, the editor's advice and friendship.

Note that the indebtedness here is metaphoric and really indicates gratitude and the willingness to return a favor rather than a legal obligation for repayment.